# If $y=\log\sqrt{\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}}$, prove that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec 2x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $y=\log\sqrt{\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x}}$, prove that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sec 2x$

I differentiated $y$ and I don't seem to get $\sec 2x$ at all. Please show me how to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster solution I found in hindsight:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log \left ( \sqrt{\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}} \right ) &= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log \left ( \frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)} \right ) \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left ( \log (1+\tan(x)) - \log(1-\tan(x)) \right ) \right )\\
&= \frac{\sec^2(x)}{2(1+\tan(x))} + \frac{\sec^2(x)}{2(1-\tan(x))}\\
&= \frac{\sec^2(x)}{1 - \tan^2(x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\cos(2x)}\\
&= \sec(2x)
\end{aligned}$$

---

A slower solution I initially found:

Note that $\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)} = \frac{\tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) + \tan(x)}{1 - \tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) \tan (x)} = \tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )$, so $\log \left ( \sqrt{\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}} \right ) = \log \left ( \sqrt{\tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )} \right )$.

Thus, we have 
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \; \log \left ( \sqrt{\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)}} \right ) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \; \log \left ( \sqrt{\tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \; \log \left (\tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right ) \right )\\
&= \frac{\sec^2 \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )}{2\tan \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )}\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right ) \cos \left ( \frac{\pi}{4} + x \right )}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2x \right )}\\
&= \frac{1}{\cos(2x)}\\
&= \sec(2x)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: What if $\dfrac\pi2>x>\dfrac\pi4$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try using log properties.

Comment: This is a very vague hint